# Blazor server error 400 fails to negotiate to server when using routing

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

[image: Blazor Routing Error]

#### Describe the bug

As shown in the attached screenshot I'm using routing:

@page "/addbrand/{BrandId:guid}"

When I refresh the url https://localhost:44379/addBrand/1abc52f3-c371-4566-847d-1a986f093396 this lead to error 400 Failed to load resource as the url of balzor negotation changed to https://localhost:44379/addBrand/_blazor/negotiate?negotiateVersion=1   instead of
https://localhost:44379/_blazor/negotiate?negotiateVersion=1

https://localhost:44379/addBrand/_framework/blazor.server.js    instead of
https://localhost:44379/_framework/blazor.server.js

and this happened to all of links in _host.cshtml file.

Got Exceptions? Yes, browser console log:
[2020-03-23T21:57:35.846Z] Information: Normalizing '_blazor' to 'https://localhost:44379/addBrand/_blazor'.
_blazor/negotiate?negotiateVersion=1:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 ()
blazor.server.js:1 [2020-03-23T21:57:35.917Z] Error: Failed to complete negotiation with the server: Error

#### Further technical details

- ASP.NET Core version: 3.1
- The IDE: VS 2019

I have reported it on [github](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/20090)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the `<base href` tag url to `~/` in your _Host.cshtml

```html
<head>
...
    <base href="~/" />
...
</head>
```