# Blazor server side - Losing connection and can't reconnect properly

Tags: c#, blazor

I have a blazor serverside app running on azure. For the most part, everything is fine. I probably have about 30 users at any time so its not huge traffic.

I have now had 2 incidents where a user keeps getting disconnected with the messages below. They have closed everything and restarted, but to no avail. After a few days the issue goes away... Its very random. Anyone have any ideas?

I think its to do with the 'Failed to deliver completion notification fron render XX'

Seems like it holds a stale connection via Signal R or something?

[image: Screenshot from edge]

PS. First time I've actually asked a question on stack overflow after using it for years. Shout if you need more details.

Comment: Related SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60822723/blazor-server-error-400-fails-to-negotiate-to-server-when-using-routing

Comment: *After a few days the issue goes away* Could it be that they are sticked to a particular server that is faulty for a reason? You could try to advice a user to completely wipe out cookies for your site and check if this helps.